# How to improve RecyclerView scrolling performance?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
class MiddleAllCurrencyAdapter(
internal var moContext: Context,
internal var moArrayList: ArrayList<CBBVModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MiddleAllCurrencyAdapter.KeyName_holder>() {

lateinit var mCBBVModel: CBBVModel
lateinit var mContBackView: ConstraintLayout
lateinit var mTxtKeyname: TextView
var ViewHeight = 0
var SelectedImgBack: ImageView = ImageView(moContext)
var SelectedImgBackwhite: ImageView = ImageView(moContext)
var mTxtDValue: TextView = TextView(moContext)
var mTxtDKey: TextView = TextView(moContext)

companion object {
    var SelectedPosition = -1
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KeyName_holder {
    return KeyName_holder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.middle_recycler_view,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

fun replaceAndRefresh(CbbvModels: List<CBBVModel>) {
    this.moArrayList.clear()
    this.moArrayList.addAll(CbbvModels)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KeyName_holder, position: Int) {
    try {
        mCBBVModel = moArrayList[position]
        holder.lPosition = position
        holder.lTxtDValue.text = mCBBVModel.Delta
        holder.lTxtDKey.text = mCBBVModel.KeyName
        holder.lTxtTValue.text = mCBBVModel.DTotalValue
        holder.lTxtSValue.text = mCBBVModel.DSellerValue
        holder.lTxtBValue.text = mCBBVModel.DBuyerValue

        if (mCBBVModel.Delta.toInt() < 0) {
            holder.lTxtDValue.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            holder.lTxtDKey.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        } else {
            holder.lTxtDValue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(moContext!!, R.color.greenU))
            holder.lTxtDKey.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(moContext!!, R.color.greenU))

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return moArrayList.size
}


inner class KeyName_holder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!),
    View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var lTxtDValue: TextView
    lateinit var lTxtTValue: TextView
    lateinit var lTxtSValue: TextView
    lateinit var lTxtBValue: TextView
    lateinit var lTxtDKey: TextView
    lateinit var lCBBVModel: CBBVModel
    lateinit var mImgBack1: ImageView
    lateinit var mImgBackwhite1: ImageView
    lateinit var mCnt1: ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var mMainView: ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var mShadowLayout1: ShadowView
    var lPosition = -1

    init {
        try {
            if (itemView != null) {
                mImgBack1 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_back)
                mImgBackwhite1 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_backwhite)
                mCnt1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cnt_1)
                lTxtDValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_DValue)
                lTxtDKey = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_DKey)
                mShadowLayout1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shadowLayout)
                mMainView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainView)

                lTxtBValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_BValue)
                lTxtSValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_SValue)
                lTxtTValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_TValue)
    }
    override fun onClick(contentClick: View) {
    }
}
}
```

How to improve RecyclerView scrolling performance in the android studio while using layout file for cell item in recycler view,
performance problem: It loads some time for scrolling and used to refresh data at every single second in recycler adapter. 
I don't have any idea for improving performance for the user to uses applications.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples of how you use the RecyclerView? (The adapter code and how you pass data to it and all that.)

Comment: yes, ill share it

Comment: Razvan S: RecyclerView Stucks scrolling scrolling and refresh the adapter data and also use xml layout file where includes 8 textboxes, 2 drawable images, and background shadow of main layout...

Comment: If you have huge and constant updates consider using [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) and `DiffUtil`

Comment: @AnkurSojitra I agree with Mohammad Omidvar. You should try ListAdapter and DiffUtil and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks all of you to helping for reducing stuck at recycleview scrolling while load new raw in list.